# Scanner.skip documentation concerning delimiters

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

According to [the javadoc for `java.util.Scanner.skip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#skip%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29), this method:

> Skips input that matches the specified pattern, **ignoring delimiters**.

But I am confused as to what the phrase 'ignoring delimeters' means because the following code throws an exception using Java 7 in Eclipse:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example
{

   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner("Hello World! Here 55");
      String piece = sc.next();

      sc.skip("World"); // Line A throws NoSuchElementException,  vs.
      sc.skip("\\sWorld"); // Line B works!
      sc.findInLine("World"); // Line C works!
   }
}
```

It does not seem to ignore delimiters when skipping, as demonstrated by Line A. However Line C appears to work even though its documentation uses the same "ignoring delimiters" phrase. Am I unclear on their concept of "ignoring delimiters" in this case or is this an actual bug? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left out the next sentence of the method's description which reads (emphasis mine):

> This method will skip input if an **anchored match** of the specified pattern succeeds.

So `Scanner` is not so much "ignoring" the delimiter, but simply trying to match the specified regular expression without taking the delimiter into account. In other words, the space before `World` is not treated as a delimiter by `skip()`, but merely part of the input that it is trying to match against.

Comment: I understand your explanation. Perhaps they should take out the phrase 'ignoring delimiters' and link to Matcher's concept of "anchoring" as I was only vaguely aware of that concept. I assumed the "anchor" would point to the next token because of that misleading phrase. Would you agree?

Comment: The anchor is the next character that the `Scanner` will read. So in this context, `Scanner.skip()` is semantically closer to `Matcher.matches()` than to `Matcher.find()`.